# Magento 2 visual swatches on sidebar?

Tags: magento2, sidebar

I'm using magento 2 and I'm trying to get the visual swatches (color, size..) on the sidebar, on the caterogy pages. I've got the visual swatches for on the product page , but on the sidebar is just text..

Answer (score 1):

go to admin,

Stores -> Attribute -> Product

Go to Color Attribute, click on that,

Change **`Catalog Input Type for Store Owner`** value to `Visual swatch` from dropdown.

Same process for `size` attribute and run indexing command.

Comment: I have already set that to Visual swatch , but it's still don't work on the side bar.. And I would also like to have some check boxes , so I can check more of them , cause now is just text , so I click a link and already sends me to the result  doesn't let me choose more options..

Comment: Have you use any extension for layer navigation?

Comment: I'm only using the Venustheme - Yume , here is the link for the theme http://www.venustheme.com/theme/ves-yume-free-magento-2-theme/

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Admin -> Stores -> Attribute -> Product -> **Color**(Attribute),

Change **Catalog Input Type for Store Owner** to **Visual swatch** and add Swatch Colors...

Go on **Storefront Properties** tab. Click on dropdown **Use in Layer Navigation** select **Filterable (with results)**.

Do not forget to clear the cache and make reindex.

Good luck! :)

Comment: I have already set up my configuration like that , but is still not showing up on the sidebar.. that's the strange thing..

Comment: And after reindex and full clear cache?
Do you have any extension for layer nav?
you can see my settings http://i.imgur.com/PjVS31M.png __  http://i.imgur.com/98kYaJQ.png __ http://i.imgur.com/gG27fy4.png

Comment: I have the same configuration , I'm only using the Venustheme - Yume  http://www.venustheme.com/theme/ves-yume-free-magento-2-theme/

Comment: OK, then just compare default luma theme and your custom.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by compare them ?

Comment: Need to find what missing in your theme, because default luma theme have thit feature.
It's not a problem in admin configuration :(

Comment: Ok , thank you for your time , another issue with this is that there are just links , for colors size ecc , and not checkboxes.. so I can only choose one option..

Comment: Try get color value in your theme, and just make custom feature for that..eg..if you can got #ffffff in variable, just make a box which have inline css, get you color in variable and set background-color: $yourVariable

Comment: Yea I was thinking about that as a solution.. What about the multiple filters , now I can only select one , but what if I want to choose more options , like color , size ecc.. as checkboxes.. cause now there are just links..

Comment: Just limit in php, eg. if attribute code == color do something else other.... :)